# Reference Dll based on Visual Studio version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to conditionally reference a `dll` based on the version of Visual Studio (`2012` or `2013`) ? If I'm on `VS2012`, I add dll1 and if I'm on `VS2013`, I add `dll2` as reference

I tried something like that `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'V12 Release'"` but it seems not to be working :

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'V11 Release'">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager\v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'V12 Release'">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Is there a way how to handle that?

Comment: In fact, I wanted to add that the two dlls have the same name, and same namespace but each one is compatible with a version of Visual Studio

Comment: Erm, wait, you use Version=12.0.0.0 for version 11.

Comment: yep, I thought about that at first but It's made that way even when I reference it manually, both of them are version 12.0.0.0

Comment: Well, that's surely why "it doesn't work".  There's a `<bindingRedirect>` in effect, Lord knows where.  I think the conventional wisdom is to build the extension with the lowest VS version you are willing to support and declare what higher versions it is compatible with in the manifest.

Comment: Do you mean if I want two versions of my extension, it would be preferable to build each one with the appropriate VS version?

Comment: That's another way, it guarantees success of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=11.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, 
processorArchitecture=MSIL" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'VisualStudio_2012' OR 
'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'"/>
```